# Simple Contract to supply eth to aave

Tags: contract-development, truffle-contract, aave

I'm trying programatically deposit using into Aave V2 Contract [Aave's Code Examples](https://github.com/aave/code-examples-protocol/blob/main/V2/Credit%20Delegation/MyV2CreditDelegation.sol)

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >= 0.4.22 < 0.8.7;

import { IERC20, ILendingPool, IProtocolDataProvider, IStableDebtToken } from './Interfaces.sol';
import { SafeERC20 } from './Libraries.sol';

/**
* This is a proof of concept starter contract, showing how uncollaterised loans are possible
* using Aave v2 credit delegation.
* This example supports stable interest rate borrows.
* It is not production ready (!). User permissions and user accounting of loans should be implemented.
* See @dev comments
*/

contract MyV2CreditDelegation {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    
    ILendingPool constant lendingPool = ILendingPool(address(0x9FE532197ad76c5a68961439604C037EB79681F0)); // Kovan
    IProtocolDataProvider constant dataProvider = IProtocolDataProvider(address(0x744C1aaA95232EeF8A9994C4E0b3a89659D9AB79)); // Kovan
    
    address owner;

    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    /**
    * Deposits collateral into the Aave, to enable credit delegation
    * This would be called by the delegator.
    * @param asset The asset to be deposited as collateral
    * @param amount The amount to be deposited as collateral
    * @param isPull Whether to pull the funds from the caller, or use funds sent to this contract
    *  User must have approved this contract to pull funds if `isPull` = true
    * 
    */
    function depositCollateral(address asset, uint256 amount, bool isPull) public {
        if (isPull) {
            IERC20(asset).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        }
        IERC20(asset).safeApprove(address(lendingPool), amount);
        lendingPool.deposit(asset, amount, address(this), 0);
    }

    /**
    * Approves the borrower to take an uncollaterised loan
    * @param borrower The borrower of the funds (i.e. delgatee)
    * @param amount The amount the borrower is allowed to borrow (i.e. their line of credit)
    * @param asset The asset they are allowed to borrow
    * 
    * Add permissions to this call, e.g. only the owner should be able to approve borrowers!
    */
    function approveBorrower(address borrower, uint256 amount, address asset) public {
        (, address stableDebtTokenAddress,) = dataProvider.getReserveTokensAddresses(asset);
        IStableDebtToken(stableDebtTokenAddress).approveDelegation(borrower, amount);
    }
    
    /**
    * Repay an uncollaterised loan
    * @param amount The amount to repay
    * @param asset The asset to be repaid
    * 
    * User calling this function must have approved this contract with an allowance to transfer the tokens
    * 
    * You should keep internal accounting of borrowers, if your contract will have multiple borrowers
    */
    function repayBorrower(uint256 amount, address asset) public {
        IERC20(asset).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        IERC20(asset).safeApprove(address(lendingPool), amount);
        lendingPool.repay(asset, amount, 1, address(this));
    }
    
    /**
    * Withdraw all of a collateral as the underlying asset, if no outstanding loans delegated
    * @param asset The underlying asset to withdraw
    * 
    * Add permissions to this call, e.g. only the owner should be able to withdraw the collateral!
    */
    function withdrawCollateral(address asset) public {
        (address aTokenAddress,,) = dataProvider.getReserveTokensAddresses(asset);
        uint256 assetBalance = IERC20(aTokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this));
        lendingPool.withdraw(asset, assetBalance, owner);
    }
}
```

I have code which consumes this like so:

```
App = {
  web3Provider: null,
  contracts: {},

  init: async function() {
    return await App.initWeb3();
  },

  initWeb3: async function() {
    // Modern dapp browsers...
    if (window.ethereum) {
      App.web3Provider = window.ethereum;
      try {
        // Request account access
        await window.ethereum.enable();
      } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
        console.error("User denied account access")
      }
    }
    // Legacy dapp browsers...
    else if (window.web3) {
      App.web3Provider = window.web3.currentProvider;
    }
    // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
    else {
      App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545');
    }
    web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);

    return App.initContract();
  },

  initContract: function() {
    $.getJSON('MyV2CreditDelegation.json', function(data) {
      // Get the necessary contract artifact file and instantiate it with @truffle/contract
      var safeYieldArtifact = data;
      App.contracts.MyV2CreditDelegation = TruffleContract(safeYieldArtifact);
    
      // Set the provider for our contract
      App.contracts.MyV2CreditDelegation.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
    });
    

    

    return App.bindEvents();
  },

  bindEvents: function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-deposit', App.handleDeposit);
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-withdrawl', App.handleWithdrawl);
  },

  handleDeposit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    
      var account = accounts[0];

      App.contracts.MyV2CreditDelegation.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        creditDelegatorInstance = instance;
        const mockETHAddress = "0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE"
        // Execute adopt as a transaction by sending account
        return creditDelegatorInstance.depositCollateral(mockETHAddress, 1, true);
      }).then(function(result) {
        //return App.markAdopted();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
  },

  handleWithdrawl: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  },
};

$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    App.init();
  });
});
```

When attempting to supply, Metamask displays an error:

> ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.

I'm running ganache

`ganache-cli --fork https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{MyProjectId}}`

The only error I see in the console is:

> Transaction: 0x9961f8a187c09fd7c9ebf803771fa161c9939268bb01552a1598807bcfdc13ff
> Gas usage: 24813
> Block Number: 12905002
> Block Time: Mon Jul 26 2021 20:38:30 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
> Runtime Error: revert

My guess is that I'm not calling the contract from Web3 appropiately

How can programatically supply Eth (Or any other token) to aave?

Comment: You can use a debugger like https://tenderly.io to pin point the source code line that is reverting on a public network transactions. Then you read the related Aave or your own source code and figure out why it is reverting.

Comment: I think that you are not getting answers because your request is way too broad. You are basically asking that someone build your whole project for you (contract, configuration and front-end).

Comment: @Undead8 I will take note of this and provide more of the code to get this working,  However, I'm not asking someone to write the whole project for me.   1. The entire contract is there.  Addtionally,  I referenced a link to the example contract in Aave V2.   So regardless one of them should work 3. I've provided the web3/truffle code which should call it.     This is a simple and common task so I'm sure someone already has the code out there.    This would be useful to the community in general
It seems more like this community is dead.

Comment: Incase anyone is wondering how to do this, I got this answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68704408/1938988)